# Получаю после отправки xml как его преобразовать в массив

Tags: php, xml

Отправляю запрос на сервер

```
 public function getSms() {
    $api_kay = $this->db->query("SELECT api_kay FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "sms_api ")->row;

    $offices = array();
    if(!empty($_POST['selected'])) {
        $result = array(
            'ttn' => array(),
            'phone' => array(),
        );

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['selected']); $i++) {
            $order_id = $_POST['selected'][$i];
            $orders = $this->db->query("SELECT telephone, ttn FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order WHERE order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "'")->rows;

            foreach ($orders as $order) {
                $result['ttn'][] = $order['ttn'];
                $result['phone'][] = $order['telephone'];
            }
        }

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['selected']); $i++) {

            $recipient = $result['phone'][$i];
            $sender = $_POST['sender'];
            $text = trim($_POST['text_sms']). $result['ttn'][$i];
            $kay = trim(implode('',$api_kay));

            $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
                <package key="' . $kay . '">
                <message>
                <msg recipient= "' . $recipient . '" sender= "' . $sender . '" type="0">' . $text . '</msg>
                </message>
                </package>';

            $offices[] = $this->sendRequest($xml);
        }
    }
    return $offices;
}
```

сервере отдает ответ виде xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <package>
     <message>
      <msg sms_id="1234568" sms_count="1">206 ответ  </msg>
     </message>
   </package>
```

Принимаю ответ

```
  $error_sms = $this->model_account_alphasms->getSms();

        print_r($error_sms);
```

я получаю массив

```
Array ( [0] => 206 [1] => 206 )
```

Записываю в базу

```
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO `" . DB_PREFIX . "sms_error` SET `error_number` ='" .$err."'");
```

но в самой базе записываться

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><package><message><msg id="0" sms_id="0" sms_count="0">206</m
```

как сделать что бы записывалась ошибка в данном случаи это 206

Comment: [Сделайте минимально воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Сейчас в у вас вопросе просто набор бессвязных данных.  Не ясно откуда вдруг взялось `206`, Ни как вдруг xml, где ни разу не встречается `206` вдруг превратился в массив `Array ( [0] => 206 [1] => 206 )`, ни откуда взялся второй xml. Неясно почему вы пишете второй xml в базу, хотя вам нужны данные из массива.